# extract table from sqlite3 database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have some large (~500MB) .db3 files with tables in them that I'd like to extract, perform some checks on and write to a .csv file. The following code shows how I open a .db3 file given its `filepath`, select data from `MY_TABLE` and return the `output` list:

```
import sqlite3
def extract_db3_table(filepath):
    output = []
    with sqlite3.connect(filepath) as connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        connection.text_factory = bytes
        cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE''')
        for row_index, row in enumerate(cursor):
            output.append(row)
    return output
```

However, the following error happens at the final iteration of the cursor:

```
  File "C:/Users/.../Documents/Python/extract_test.py", line 10, in extract_db3_table
    for row_index, row in enumerate(cursor):

DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed
```

The code runs for every iteration up until the last, when this error is thrown. I have tried different .db3 files but the problem persists. The same error is also thrown if I use the `cursor.fetchall()` method instead of the cursor for loop in my example above.

Do I have to use a `try...catch` block within the loop somehow and `break` the loop once this error is thrown or is there another way to solve this? Any insight is very much appreciated!

The reason I use `bytes` as the `connection.text_factory` is because some `TEXT` values in my table are not able to be converted to a `str`, so in my full code I use a `try...catch` block when decoding the `TEXT` values to UTF-8 and ignore the rows where this does not work.

Comment: Are you sure that database file is intact? Does [PRAGMA integrity_check](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_integrity_check) succeed?

Comment: PRAGMA integrity_check gave me 100 items, mostly things like "invalid page number" and "Rowid 1969479 out of order". When I tried to run PRAGMA integrity_check(1000) and then fetch the results it gave me the same error as before: "database disk image is malformed"

Comment: That database file got corrupted. Restore it from the backup.